# How to remove heading key from maatwebsite/excel in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.6, maatwebsite-excel

How to remove number from first row in Maatwebsite/Excel
Please help me to solve the issue.

```js
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $data = array($row['user_name'], $row['full_name'], $row['address'], $row['phone_number']);
}
return Excel::create('export_excel', function ($excel) use ($data) {
    $excel->sheet('mySheet', function ($sheet) use ($data) {
        $sheet->fromArray($data);
    });
})->download('xlsx');
```

Comment: you need to remove number for first row only?

Comment: $ctr = 1;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
 if ($ctr == 1) 
  $data = array(
   preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $row['user_name']), 
   preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $row['full_name']), 
   preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $row['address']), 
   preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $row['phone_number'])
  );
 else 
  $data = array($row['user_name'], $row['full_name'], $row['address'], $row['phone_number']);
}